# JsPDF Sub-Array Data Push

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using Jspdf and Jspdf-autotable to generate PDF in my project. But I couldn't figure out how to push Sub-Array value in row. Here is example of JSON-

```
[{
            "voucherId":"18010110004",
            "date":"2018-01-01",
            "refNo":"0",
            "narration":null,
            "inWordTk":"Three Thousand  Taka  Only",
            "detailsList":[  
               {  
                  "ledgerName":"Cash",
                  "drAmount":3000,
                  "crAmount":0
               },
               {  
                  "ledgerName":"New Admission Fee Collection",
                  "drAmount":0,
                  "crAmount":3000
               }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

And i want it to be liked this photo
[JsPdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du3mX.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply take out that data first. Something like this in your case:

```
var header = ['Ledger', 'Debit', 'Credit']
var data = objects.map(obj => Object.values(obj.detailList))
doc.autoTable(header, data)
```